# is it possible to make a combined installer for an electron app and a python?

Tags: electron, windows-installer, exe, electron-builder, electron-packager

I have an electron application.
my app is using python for her living.
by using electron-packager and then electron-installer-windows
by the tutorial in https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-installer-windows
i made .exe(portable version) and .msi(installation version) files out of it.
the thing is, i want to give my clients 1 file (either msi or exe) that will let them use the application. (will install python and then automatically install my electron msi).
any suggestions?